# 97 Honda Civic putting and stuttering after a radiator hose failed

Tags: honda, troubleshooting, civic

Whenever I am giving the car gas, it starts to putt and stutter.

My car was overheating. I looked under the hood and noticed one of my hoses to the radiator had been pulled from it. I put the hose back on the radiator and clamped it down. I had no antifreeze; I filled it up with some water just to make it home. By the time I made it to my house, the engine had started smoking.

I looked under the hood and couldn't tell if anything was undone or not in its right place. The next morning I found that one of the hoses had busted.

I replaced it and filled up with antifreeze and water, cranked it up and everything was sounding fine. But now when I drive it, it does the putter dance.

I have my thoughts -- either the catalytic convertor, the thermostat, or the fuel injector -- but don't have the money to spend on guesses. Given the background, I could see the thermostat being bad, but I don't know if that would make the car stutter.

Comment: Could you describe the "putting and stuttering" in more detail?

Comment: Its almost like a vacuum cleaner, like you have a steady air flow then you put your hand in front of the suction. That's now it feels when I am driving. The putting starts when from what I want to say is the exhaust getting clogged. I gave it gas and it makes almost a clogging feeling and then "Putt Pupu Putt" the check engine light has came on and then starts to flash

Answer (score 2):

If everything was running fine prior to the hose breaking I would check and see if you have water under the distributor cap or the plug wire connections.